# TypeScript: Type of a class

Tags: typescript, mixins

I simply want to create a function that takes a class as argument:

```
const mixin = (traits: Object) =>
  (baseClass: class) => { // What type to put here?
    Object.assign(baseClass.prototype, traits)
    return baseClass
  }
```

But I don't know what type I have to put to specify I'm working with a Constructor Function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics to return the right class constructor:

```
const mixin = (traits: any) =>
    <T>(baseClass: { new (): T }) => {
        Object.assign(baseClass.prototype, traits);
        return baseClass;
    }

class A {}

let o = mixin({})(A); // typeof o is new () => A
let a = new o(); // typeof a is A
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20mixin%20%3D%20(traits%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(baseClass%3A%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(baseClass.prototype%2C%20traits)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20baseClass%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20o%20%3D%20mixin(%7B%7D)(A)%3B%20%2F%2F%20typeof%20o%20is%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20o()%3B%20%2F%2F%20typeof%20a%20is%20A))

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I'm still facing some issues : `mixin(Speaker)(class { })` works, but `mixin(Speaker)(class extends Mammal { })` does not.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, was doing something bad. Works perfectly. Thanks.